# Fortran: Avoiding Zeros in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrix

I have a 10 by 10 matrix with only one non-zero element at A(1,1) and A(10,10), 4 non-zero elements on the second and 9th rows: A(2,1),A(2,2),A(2,3),A(2,4) and A(9,7), A(9,8), A(9,9) and A(9,10). The 3rd to 8th rows have 5 diagonal non-zero elements. How do i do a matrix-vector multiplication using only the non-zeros elements?